# How to retrieve N random records from stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I retrieve N random records from a set of X records we have in total. For example, if we have a table with 2000 links to different pages on our website how do we retrieve 10 random records?

Comment: [Random order by performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680310/random-order-by-performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dynamics SQL like this. Note that this needs more work since some edge cases are not covered such as COUNT(*) returning 0 or cases where record count is greater than COUNT(*) and such.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RandomNRecords
(
 @recordCount int
)
as 
begin
declare @counter int
declare @sqlQuery nvarchar(2000)

SET @sqlQuery = '

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
f1 varchar(50),
f2 varchar(50),
f3 int,
id int identity(1,1)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM Table1

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable
WHERE id in ('

SELECT @recordCount = COUNT(*) From Table1

SET @counter = 0
WHILE @counter < @recordCount
BEGIN
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
    SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + CONVERT(varchar,Round((@recordCount * Rand()), 0)) + ','     
END;

SET @sqlQuery = SUBSTRING(@sqlQuery, 1, LEN(sqlQuery) - 1) --remove last comma 
SET @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + ')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

- [NEWID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @numberOfRecordsToGet int = 5
select top (@numberOfRecordsToGet) * from name_of_your_tbl order by newid()
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in store procedure

declare @N varchar(10)

set @N='10'

exec(' SELECT TOP '+@N+' * FROM tableName ORDER BY NEWID()')